# Need an example to understand that - when debug is True then the exceptions propagate up

Tags: python, flask

```
Python 3.7.4
Flask 1.1.1
Werkzeug 0.15.5
```

Need an example to understand that - when debug is True then the exceptions propagate up.

In the example below, the Debug mode is enabled and hence the [PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/?highlight=propagate#PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS) should be auto enabled. **This should result in Exceptions to be re-raised rather than being handled by the app’s error handlers.**

I tried code such that the root endpoint raises ZeroDivisionError. However, there is no propagation irrespective of whether the debug = True / False:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    1/0
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.errorhandler(ZeroDivisionError)
def handle_bad_request(e):
    return 'bad!', 500

app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: You are handling the exception. The exception can't propagate unless it is unhandled.

Comment: I have updated my code now

Answer (score 0):

"a call to the root endpoint (that raises divide by zero exception) ": No, because you catch *any* exception immediately. That leaves nothing to propagate. Btw, a "bare except" is not good. Always catch specific exceptions.

There is no code in your application that raises a 404 exception. Werkzeug does not know what application to send the request to and returns a 404 **before** the request gets into your application, so your error handler is never invoked.

Comment: I have updated my code - can you check now - I have not handled any exception now

Comment: You are returning a response from your error handler. Werkzeug takes that as "it has been handled". There is no magic involved. If you want it to propagate exceptions, you have to re-raise, or call abort with an appropriate HTTP error. You can also omit the handler altogether, that will also trigger the debugger.